# How does loop.parent actually work?

Tags: php, twig

I have a for loop nested in another for loop in my template, and need to grab the index of the outer loop for a generated value in my inner loop.  I thought `loop.parent` would to the trick, but I'm getting an `Array to string conversion exception`.

Am I misreading what little the [twig docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html) are describing?  And, regardless, is there a way for me to access that outer loop index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.  Use `loop.parent.loop.index0`.